# Not working 'PImage' as Class Property in Processing.js

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

What i was trying to do is, declare a class which has an Image as it's property.Then I am declaring an Object of that class and call draw function.But it's not working....Why? Here is my processing.js part of my .html page

```js
 <script type="text/processing">

        PImage starImage;

        void setup(){
            size(400,400);
            smooth();

            starImage = loadImage("star.png");


        }

        var Star = function(x,y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.img  = starImage;
        };

        Star.prototype.drawStar = function(){
            image(this.img,this.x,this.y,50,50);
        };

        var obj = new Star(50,50);

        draw = function(){
            obj.drawStar();
        };

    </script>
```

But if I change "image(this.img,this.x,this.y,50,50);" to "image(starImage,this.x,this.y,50,50);",it's works.That seems assignment of 'starImage' (PImage) in this.img is not working.

Comment: remember that images need preloading in JS context, so you need a `/* @pjs preload="star.png" */` at the very least (See http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#synchronousIO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you're creating your `Star` object before you load your `starImage` `PImage`. Try refactoring your code to make sure that you load the image before you create the `Star` object.

Here is how you'd do it in pure Processing:

```
PImage starImage;

Star obj;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  smooth();

  starImage = loadImage("star.png");
  obj = new Star(50, 50, starImage);
}

class Star{

  float x;
  float y;
  PImage img;

  public Star(float x, float y, PImage img){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.img = img;
  }

  public void drawStar(){
    image(this.img, this.x, this.y, 50, 50);
  }
}

void draw(){
  obj.drawStar();
}
```

That should work in Processing.js too. Notice that the `Star` object isn't being created until **after** the image is loaded.

Comment: also remember the `@pjs preload` instruction (http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#synchronousIO)